# Mongoose Atlas connection hanging

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to abstract a tutorial for MEAN stack to use MongoAtlas rather than a local instance.
My Mongoose connection to Atlas DB is working (in so far as I can connect to the DB). But I'm not able to do a save(). I believe that this is something to do with the way I'm creating my connection object, but I don't seem to be able to put my finger on the problem.

I assumed that by adding bufferCommands = false that this would tell me that the reason it wasn't working was I'd opened the connection object wrongly, but I'm not seeing any error - just hanging.

## product.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema ({
    imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required:true}
});
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-dpwmr.gcp.mongodb.net/Shopping?retryWrites=true', {useNewUrlParser:true})

module.exports = connection.model('Product', schema);
```

## product-seeder.js

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.set('bufferCommands', false);
var products =[ 
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/250/?random',
        title: 'Item 1',
        description: 'This is a thing',
        price: 10
        }),
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/251/?random',
        title: 'Item 2',
        description: 'This is another thing',
        price: 14
        }),
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/253/?random',
        title: 'Item 3',
        description: 'This is a slightly longer description',
        price: 30
        })
];


var done = 0;
for (i=0; i++; i<products.length){
    products[i].save(function(err, res){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            exit();
        }
        done++;
        if (done === products.length){
            exit();
        }
    });
}

function exit(){
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

I expected this to create a new document 'products' and write to it in the Shopping collection, but that's not happening, just lots of nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using `mongoose.connect()` instead of `mongoose.createConnection`, it's been related to some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working with a combination of:

- Using mongoose.connect()
- Adding the DB name to the options object
- Making sure that the DB writes are done with proper promises, not weird loops.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema ({
    imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required:true}
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0-dpwmr.gcp.mongodb.net/', {dbName:'Shopping', useNewUrlParser:true})
.then( () => {
    console.log('Connection to the Atlas Cluster is successful!')
  })
  .catch( (err) => console.error(err));

const conn = mongoose.connection;
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

```
var Product = require('../models/product');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var products =[ 
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/250/?random',
        title: 'Item 1',
        description: 'This is a thing',
        price: 10
        }),
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/251/?random',
        title: 'Item 2',
        description: 'This is another thing',
        price: 14
        }),
    new Product({
        imagePath:'https://picsum.photos/253/?random',
        title: 'Item 3',
        description: 'This is a slightly longer description',
        price: 30
        })
];
const conn = mongoose.connection;

processArray(products);

async function processArray (array) {
   for (const item of products){
       console.log (item)
       await item.save();
   }
   conn.close();
}
```